# Изменение innerText после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: html

Исходный код:

```
<form method="post" action="file.html"><input type="text" id="text" name="text" value=""><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку отправляется форма в файл `"file.html"`. В моём случае текст поля `"text"`  при отправлении в файл сохраняется в нём вот таким образом (содержимое file.html):

```
<table><tbody><tr><td><span class="text">...полученный текст...</span></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Если, допустим, в файле `"file.html"` значение innerText у переменной `<span>` содержит символы, то можно ли при получении формы удалить всё значение innerText у переменной `<span>` и установить то, что получено?

Comment: @Никита___, не совсем понятно.
Что такое innerText? В примере его нет. <span> - это не переменная, это тег.

Comment: @Никита___, вы хотите, чтобы текст, набранный пользователем, был записан в файл file.html? Опишите более подробно, что должно происходить, и случай, когда два раза был отправлен разный текст.